# How to save breakpoint in visual basic 6

Tags: vb6, breakpoints

How can I save my breakpoints in Visual Basic 6?
Are there any add-ins? For now I have MZ-Tools, but unfortunately they don't save breakpoints.

Comment: When you say Visual Basic 6, do you mean using Interdev? Aren't breakpoints saved from one session to the next? (I can't remember, to be honest, but I would think they were)

Comment: Visual Studio 6 is the name of the IDE. When you close the IDE all breakpoints have gone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure about third party tools, but you could always use:

```
Debug.Assert False
```

Just remember to remove it when you're done.

Comment: +1. I think there are some third party tools, but this is a good practical way. You could mark the statements with a TODO comment to help you remember to remove them later.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a nice VB6 add-in to save breakpoints on exit.
http://www.darinhiggins.com/bookmarksave-addin-for-vb6

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link! Very cool. I'm sure this would solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Link is now a 404 dead link.

Comment: @StarPilot: It is probably here [BookmarkSave For VB6](https://bookmarksavevb6.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3):

This is what the `Stop` statement does, i.e. act as a persistent unconditional breakpoint.

Comment: However that said, using Assert has the advantage of being automatically omitted in a compiled project.