# Call vbp inside vb6 IDE

Tags: shell, vb6

I have to debug a group of vb6 projects.

There is a root project (say toolbar.exe). This program is basically a toolbar that call another .exe

Ex:Call Shell(App.Path & "\ModMag2008.exe ", argument ......

I have the ModMag2008.vbp and would like to call it for debug (it is in the same project group as toolbar.vbp)

So i would start debugging toolbar.vbp and go on to debugging ModMag2008.vbp

Is this possible?

Note: I cannot change the architecture.

Comment: So you have an .exe which call the other one (ModMag2008)? And you to debug the called program(ModMag2008)?  Why you just not start ModMag2008.vbp in VB6 IDE with proper command line arguments (in options)?

Comment: Hi,"Why you just not start ModMag2008.vbp in VB6 IDE with proper command line arguments (in options)? " Because modmag2008 arguments change very often. Besides modmag2008 calls another .exe and so on. Productivity would increase by n factor if i just could debug without constantly editing parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug VB6 application, called as .exe from the other application I see two possibilities:

1/Change the callig code to call application thorough Visulal Studio 6

```
Call Shell(App.Path & "\ModMag2008.exe ", argument ......
```

is to be replaced by

```
Call Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE /r " &  App.Path & "\ModMag2008.exe  /cmd ", argument ......
```

see: [Working with Command Line Switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231236%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

2/ Use Visual studio.net to debug VB6 binaries - debuging is not too convenient - but it is not necessary to modify original application: [Debugging VB6 binaries in Visual Studio .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2004/11/09/254602.aspx)

Comment: Hi ivanH, It's almost that. I used Call Shell("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE /r " & App.Path & "\ModMag2008.vbp  /cmd ". The problem is that VB detects the project is already open (is in the vbg) and throws "already open error". I i remove from the vbg it works but breakpoints are not saved with a vb6 project so i can't stop it.

Comment: @user1241433: There is probably no solution for opening .vbg twice. For breakpoints try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501850/how-to-save-breakpoint-in-visual-basic-6 (I have not tested it).

Comment: Hi ivanH. Using shell with breakpoint solution you pointed out. Not ideal but seems to be the only solution. Tkx